# Is there an attribute to mark the class or method to be thread safe in .NET?

Tags: .net, multithreading

In .NET how can I know if a class or method is thread safe or not? Is it by default not thread safe?

Comment: What purpose would you like such an attribute to serve?

Comment: May be a sort of code documentation to warn the class user

Comment: If he just wants documentation, he could put it in the <remarks/> section.

Comment: @Saunders: may be for documentation you are right, but if I want the compiler/runtime warn/prevent me

Answer (score 6):

This is no attribute for this: you have to read the documentation for each item your are interested in.  You can't make something thread safe simply by adding an attribute to it.  That's like taking an orange and putting a sticker on it that says, "Apple".

Of course, the same thing is true for serialization and it didn't stop them there, but still: no attribute. Read the docs.

Comment: All static methods and properties are assumed to be thread safe by default (i.e. unless documented otherwise), for instance methods the assumption is that they are not.

Comment: Assuming a method is not thread safe when it is causes no harm, assuming one is thread safe when its not can be nasty. Your better off to assume nothing is thread safe unless indicated.

Answer (score 2):

No, and it would be pointless.

Let's assume I have a thread safe List, it has three **Thread Safe™** methods:

```
void Add( something);
void Remove(index);
int GetCount();
something GetElementAt(index);
```

Thread one:

```
for 1 to 100 do
 list.Add(12);
```

Thread **two and three**:

```
while( list.GetCount() >0)
{
    list.Remove(0);
}
```

The code above will crash (sooner or later) because the list might change between the time you call  `GetCount` and `Remove`

Answer (score 1):

I got my back on Joel Coehoorn on this one, would be easy to 'fake' such claims.

Why not add the threadsafe text in the function description

Comment: I wouldn't worry so much about 'faking' it.  But concurrency is hard: it would be very likely that a bug has slipped through and that attribute is just incorrect.

Comment: But if the attribute is incorrect, it's likely that the documentation (if any) would be just as incorrect.

Comment: I totally agree @JimMischel, but Joel wasn't the one who was advocating for documentation. At least attributes are machine-readable, allowing for, at a minimum, automated enumeration, filtering, reporting etc. of the attributed methods, and potentially even some weak forms of static analysis and/or error prevention. Attributes are the way to go, but you'd need an elaborate and comprehensive system of them to capture concurrency semantics in any truly useful way. For .NET, I'm not aware of any such design or proposal.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make all access to your object serial via `IContributeObjectSink/IContextAttribute` although this will suffer from a large performance hit since it will require your object to subclass `MarshalByRefObject`,context creation overhead, etc...

Answer (score 1):

To mark a class as thread-safe you can use a class level `[Synchronization]` attribute from the `System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts` namespace. Be aware to inherit your class from the  `ContextBoundObject` to make it context-sensitive.

```
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;

// Every member of this class is thread-safe... 
[Synchronization]
public class ThreadSafeClass: ContextBoundObject
{
        // Some functionality... 

}
```

Comment: Huh, neat. Unfortunately this only works on .NET Framework 4.x projects, as this attribute (and all of `System.Runtime.Remoting` was killed-off since .NET Core and .NET 5.0+). Oh well.

Answer (score -1):

There is no use case scenario of making a class synchronized, as far as method is concerned you use following coding style:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]   
void MyMethod()   
{   
DoSomething();   
}
```

Comment: The problem is; that still doesn't imply that the method is thread-safe -because another thread could be calling a different method that *doesn't* have the [MethodImpl], thus trashing each-other. Likewise even if all fields are readonly, fields on child objects could be mutable, and cause problems.

Comment: Even if this so-called "coding style" *could* signify something (see numerous other comments on this page), the `MethodImplOptions.Synchronized` flag has the opposite meaning of what the OP is looking for. This flag is meant to indicate that the method is **not** thread-safe. From the documentation: "The method can be executed by only one thread at a time."