# How do I detect & show to a caller that my method does not support concurrent invocation?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading, concurrency

How do I:

1. detect that my method was called concurrently by 2 or more
   threads
2. show to a caller that my method does not support
   concurrent invocation

Haven't seen this done anywhere but I think it would be a great idea to start doing something like this in my code. Maybe there is a template/design pattern I can use? Just looking for advice on the correct way to do this.

Comment: You can't. You need to provide documentation stating your library is not thread safe and hope that no one uses it threaded. Ulitmately it's not your reponsibility how it's consumed/if it's consumed incorrectly

Comment: @Liam, I respectfully disagree. I think the developer of the code should ensure that people can't call his/her code in an incorrect way to reduce the finger pointing phenomenon.

Comment: This would be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/658199/1662459 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Easy, provide synchronization. In other words, make your code thread safe by adding a big honking lock around it and attempting to enter it at the start of the method. If the lock is already taken, rather than waiting as thread safe code would do, throw an exception. `Monitor.TryEnter` is your friend. The main problem with this is that you're adding a ton of boilerplate everywhere to accommodate someone who foolishly ignores the fact that *no code* is thread safe unless documented to be that way.

Comment: Use `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] ` in function definition and implement lock as suggested by @JeroenMostert

Comment: Note, also, that doing this for every individual method is *still* no guarantee that you will detect concurrency problems. If a thread expects to own an object and no thread manipulating the object in the background, a particular sequence of calls that would be safe in isolation suddenly is no longer safe with another thread mucking things up. It *is* possible to detect this as well, by maintaining a version field and/or thread-local storage, but unless you are a special kind of heavily used class (like `Dictionary` or `List`) this doesn't pay off.

Comment: Another way would be to remember the thread which created the object (so, in constructor) and not allow to call methods from another thread. That is called thread affinity and often used in for example UI frameworks (wpf, win forms).